# Python install package name collisions

Tags: python, namespaces, package, setuptools

I have a project that looks like this :

```
.
├── A
│   ├── setup.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── a.py
│   └── data.py
└── B
    ├── b.py
    └── data.py
```

I don't have control over `A` but I would like to use it within `B/b.py`. I can't rewrite any code within folder `A` (except `setup.py`).

I tried this:

```py
# File A/setup.py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(name='packageA', version='1.0', packages=find_packages())
```

With the following installation/tests:

```sh
$ cd B
$ pip install -e ../A
$ python -c "import a; print(a)"
<module 'a' from 'A/a.py'>
$ python -c "import data; print(data)"
<module 'data' from 'B/data.py'> 
# How to get the same for <module 'data' from 'A/data.py'>?
```

The name collision bothers me here, I would like to be able to import both `A/data.py` and `B/data.py` in `b.py`. I wanted to know if there is a way around this?

I would like to be able to write something like:

```sh
$ python -c "from A import data; print(data)"
<module 'data' from 'A/data.py'>
```

I tried to have `setup.py` one level above (in the root directory), but if I do that then I have problems within `A`:

```sh
$ cd B
$ pip install -e ..
$ python -c "from A import data; print(data)"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "A/data.py", line 1, in <module>
    from a import some_function
ImportError: cannot import name 'some_function' from 'a' (unknown location)
```

If I could rewrite `A/data.py` I could just do this (but I can't):

```py
from A.a import some_function
```

Is it possible to modify `setup.py` to encapsulate `A` under a (fake) module name? Any solution is welcome.

Comment: Make a new package in `B`, move the module files inside it, adapt the imports.

Comment: I could, but if `A` changes I would have to redo this all over again, right?

Comment: No, why? The issue here is: `A` defines a top-level module `data`, `B` defines a top-level module `data`, there's a name clash (similar to the problem "I have two files named `data.py` in the same directory"). In order to resolve it, you can either: rename the module (one of the `data.py` files is renamed) or change it's import path (one of the `data.py` files wanders one level deeper in a separate directory under `A` or `B`).

Comment: Ah ok, I think get it, instead of having `A/data.py` and `B/data.py` you suggest to have  `A/data.py` and `B/somename/data.py`?

Comment: Exactly, also create an empty `B/somename/__init__.py` to mark `somename` a package. Your imports should now be: `import data` imports from `A/data.py`, `import somename.data` imports from `B/somename/data.py`.

Comment: This is why top-level modules are (almost) always bad. If you plan to redistribute the code, creating a top-level package with a meaningful name that will contain the modules is always a good idea.

Comment: That makes sense indeed. I'll try to work with that idea.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple possible solutions:

1. Install A as a package. `cd A && python3 setup.py install`.
   Presumably this is an installable package. Now you can import A as you would normally expect.
2. Add A to `PYTHONPATH`. It's useful when you are programming in `B` but need information extracted from `A`. So you can modify the content in A e.g. debug messages and still have your program work. `PYTHONPATH=/path/to/A python -c "import a; print(a)"`
3. You can create start the program from a parent folder import them like normal modules. Make sure you are [using relative imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python).

---

> ```
> $ cd B
> $ pip install -e ../A
> $ python -c "import a; print(a)"
> <module 'a' from 'A/a.py'>
> $ python -c "import data; print(data)"
> <module 'data' from 'B/data.py'> 
> # How to get the same for <module 'data' from 'A/data.py'>?
> ```
>
> The name collision bothers me here, I would like to be able to import
>   both A/data.py and B/data.py in b.py. I wanted to know if there is a
>   way around this?
>
> I would like to be able to write something like:
>
> ```
> $ python -c "from A import data; print(data)"
> <module 'data' from 'A/data.py'>
> ```

You do `from A import data`. Then you have "`A/data.py`". In case of name collisions you could also do `from a import data as newname`.
This assumes you have `A` installed as a python module. (Be it over `setup.py install`, `pip install` or adding the library to `PYTHONPATH`.)